# MySQL modified the "Default" and "Extra" value for timestamp fields

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel migrations to create `users` table. It has `created_at` and `updated_at` fields which have been created using `$table->timestamps();`

The resulting table structure looks like this;

[image]

Why do both of the timestamp fields have a default value? As far as I'm concerned Laravel migrations `$table->timestamps();` doesn't set the default value for timestamp.

Also, the `created_at` field's "Extra" has been set to `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I don't think Laravel migrations set this either.

Does anyone know why MySQL behave this way? I'm using **MySQL 5.7.10** by the way.

**UPDATE:** As of Laravel v5.2.24 timestamps have been made nullable by default, so this won't be a problem anymore - [commit](https://github.com/illuminate/database/commit/7ec6a1beb3fc5ba1ed70a5e9661c1bb240603673)

Comment: U can nt set two column as timestamp on update

Comment: I didn't set the `on update` value. In fact, I didn't want that to be set at all. MySQL did set that automatically.

Comment: Than alter yur column

Comment: ALTER TABLE YourTable MODIFY YourColumn DEFAULT NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to differences between MySQL versions and strict mode, specifically <= 5.6 and 5.7 as strict mode is now enabled by default. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11518

The solution for now seems to be either use `$table->nullableTimestamps()` or manually defining both `created_at` and `updated_at` columns as below

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
```